# How to grep/find for a list of file names?

Tags: linux, grep, find

So for example, I have a text document of a list of file names I may have in a directory. I want to grep or use find to find out if those file names exist in a specific directory and the subdirectories within it. Current I can do it manually via `find . | grep filename` but that's one at a time and when I have over 100 file names I need to check to see if I have them or not that can be really pesky and time-consuming.

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

`xargs` is what you want here. The case is following:

Assume you have a file named `filenames.txt` that contains a list of files

```
a.file 
b.file 
c.file 
d.file 
e.file
```

and only `e.file` doesn't exist.

the command in terminal is:

```
cat filenames.txt | xargs -I {} find . -type f -name {}
```

the output of this command is:

```
a.file
b.file
c.file
d.file
```

Maybe this is helpful.

Comment: So as a test I made 3 folders, the main folder then two sub directories

In the first sub directory I put 4 Filenames labeled as
123
234
654
999

in the second sub directory I put 3 Filenames labeled as
457
546
6969

When searching I had this issue:
$ cat filenames.txt | xargs find
find: ‘6969\r’: No such file or directory
find: ‘123\r’: No such file or directory
find: ‘234\r’: No such file or directory
find: ‘999’: No such file or directory

Comment: `cat filenames.txt | xargs -I {} find . -type f -name {}`, a complex arguments setting should be used in `xargs`

Answer (score 0):

If the files didn't move, since the last time, updatedb ran, often < 24h, your fastest search is by locate.

Read the filelist into an array and search by locate. In case the filenames are common (or occur as a part of other files), grep them by the base dir, where to find them:

```
< file.lst mapfile filearr
locate ${filearr[@]} | grep /path/where/to/find
```

If the file names may contain whitespace or characters, which might get interpreted by the bash, the usual masking mechanisms have to been taken.

Answer (score 0):

A friend had helped me figure it out via `find . | grep -i -Ff filenames.txt`